# How to remove # from vuejs root router?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

When I go to http://localhost:8080/
It redirects to http://localhost:8080/#/

Why it added "#" ?

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'    
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import List from './components/list'
import PostForm from './components/postform'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(VueRouter)             

const routes = [               
  { path: '/', component: List, name: 'root' },
  { path: '/posts/new', component: PostForm }
]     

const router = new VueRouter({ 
  routes
})  

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App),         
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: This explains the differences in routing modes: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default VueRouter uses `hash mode`.

You can change the mode to `history` if you want:

```
const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
})
```

Probably the main reason for doing this is that, if you use `history` mode you need to have a special setup for your web server to handle the urls properly. When using `hash bangs` it works out of the box.